# Application crash, not able to terminate process

Tags: windows-7, crash, process

I'm having a serious problem with my laptop, everytime that some application crash, It just freezes then I close the window of the application but the process is still running and **I'm not able to terminate the process not even by forcing it.**

A bit of background:

I'm running windows 7, recently installed few months ago.
Everything was fine but once [somehow it started asking for disk check before initiate (even if I let it start, It won't)](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/performance-maintenance/361042d1433180854t-windows-tries-perform-chkdsk-every-boot-but-fails-img_20150601_203931.jpg), like this image I took from internet, shows what exactly happens to me.

It's like when updating it turned off accidentally (as I can remember, it never happened) and some files are missing. Not sure tho.

Since then, *I just ignore that message until I can finally format my lap and put linux on it* (I'm desperatly waiting for that, so tired of Windows even if it's for studies).

Now I want to know if there is any other way to kill the process, because it's very annoying having an application that crash all the time, and having to manually restart my laptop everytime.

This may happen with any application like *steam*, *skype*, etc. So it can't be the applications.

I've tried the clasic ***end task*, *terminate process* (on task manager)** and even running a command prompt as administrator with `taskkill /f /pid ...`

It remains as I never did anything. Just won't terminate the process, so I can not open the same application and if I try to turn off my lap normally, It won't let me since there is a "process still running". I need to do it manually every time.

TL:DR;

**What other alternatives do I have to sucessfully terminate a process?**

Or maybe I'm focusing my problem in a wrong way and I may need to fix the chdisk problem first.